# SQL Error (Feed Me) when matching entries

Tags: entries, plugin-feedme, postgresql

I'm currently getting the following error when matching on an entry field.

`Offers Test: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown LINE 3: WHERE "id" LIKE $1 ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. The SQL being executed was: SELECT "structureId" FROM "sections" WHERE "id" LIKE '%' LIMIT 1 - Schema.php:664`

Currently, I have two channels one is called "Brands" and the other "Offers". Offers has an Entry field which I'm trying to match on this field, see the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been fixed in the latest version of Feed Me ([3.0.2.1](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/releases) at time of writing). Do feel free to comment if not, or get in touch via the [Feed Me support channels](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/support/get-support)